# HAProxy forward client IP to backend

Tags: reverse-proxy, haproxy

I am trying to forward client/source IP to my backend server using x-forwarded-for. I am using libwebsockets and the client IP is seen as 127.0.0.1.

I have tried looked at and tried various solutions and none have worked for me.

haproxy -vw

HA-Proxy version 1.6.3 2015/12/25

```
frontend firstbalance
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/xip.io/temp/cert.pem
    mode http
    option forwardfor
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https if { ssl_fc }
    capture request header X-Forwarded-For len 50


 backend lws_traffic
    balance roundrobin
    mode http
    option forwardfor
    server lws00 127.0.0.1:8000  check
```

Comment: *"using x-forward-for"*  Do you mean `X-Forwarded-For`?

Comment: yes, I have updated the question with the proper edit

Answer (score 0):

just try with this config :

```
frontend haproxynode
    bind *:80
    mode http
    default_backend backendnodes

backend backendnodes
    balance roundrobin
    option forwardfor
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
    option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:localhost
    server node1 backendserver:8080 check
```